# Kivy on Android: urlopen error [Errno 4] non-recoverable failure in name resolution

Tags: android, python, kivy

This Kivy program works on my Windows computer but not when I package it with buildozer and run it on Android.  On Android it gives the error:

```
I/python  ( 2173): <urlopen error [Errno 4] non-recoverable failure in name resolution.>
```

Here is the program:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import json

try:
    # For Python 3.x
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

SETTINGS_URL = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/'
                'SpotterRF/jekyll-updater/master/package.json')


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        response = urlopen(SETTINGS_URL)
        file_bytes = response.read()
        file_string = file_bytes.decode('utf-8')
        settings_dict = json.loads(file_string)

        return Label(text=settings_dict["name"])


MyApp().run()
```

`buildozer.spec` has `requirements = fysom, uuid, dropbox, six, kivy, pytz, requests`

Full adb log:

```
I/python  ( 2173): ['/data/data/org.test.lanki/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/org.test.lanki/files/lib/site-python']

I/python  ( 2173): Android path ['/data/data/org.test.lanki/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/org.test.lanki/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/data/org.test.lanki/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/data/org.test.lanki/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/org.test.lanki/files', '/data/data/org.test.lanki/files/_applibs']

I/python  ( 2173): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__

I/python  ( 2173): Run user program, change dir and execute main.py

I/python  ( 2173): [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/org.test.lanki/files/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-05-12_3.txt

I/python  ( 2173): [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0

I/python  ( 2173): [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, May 12 2016, 21:42:08) 

I/python  ( 2173): [GCC 4.8]

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 22 -101 -9 166 -1 2147483647 0x3000 gsm|lte level=3

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 22 -101 -9 166 -1 2147483647 0x3000 gsm|lte

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=3

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): updateTelephonySignalStrength, No signal level. mPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mContentDescriptionPhoneSignal = Trois barres de signaux téléphoniques

D/HeadsetPhoneState( 3820): Signal level : previous=3 curr=3

D/CustomFrequencyManagerService(  980): releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1958400  uid : 1000  pid : 980  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@15

D/CustomFrequencyManagerService(  980): FrequencyrequestList.getNextCStateDisableRequest, index: 5

I/python  ( 2173): [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f0205d9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=Bell wifiLabel="Mawer" emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="Mawer" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02052e/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020154/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f02052e/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0203b8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_lte mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f020157/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_4g mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0205d9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f0202c7/com.android.systemui:drawable/qs_tile_wifi_signal_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f020590/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_no_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0205b6/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f0205d9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=Bell wifiLabel="Mawer" emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="Mawer" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02052e/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020154/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f02052e/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0203b8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_lte mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f020157/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_4g mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0205d9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f0202c7/com.android.systemui:drawable/qs_tile_wifi_signal_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f02058b/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_in mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0205b6/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1213): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

I/python  ( 2173):  /data/data/org.test.lanki/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom

I/python  ( 2173):  (ImportError: No module named cdrom)

I/python  ( 2173): [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)

I/python  ( 2173): [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame

I/python  ( 2173): URL Error: Could not download settings json files.

I/python  ( 2173): <urlopen error [Errno 4] non-recoverable failure in name resolution.>

I/WindowState(  980): WIN DEATH: Window{a154366 u0 d0 SurfaceView}

I/SurfaceFlinger(  257): id=2635 Removed TurfaceView (5/8)

W/InputDispatcher(  980): channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

E/InputDispatcher(  980): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

I/SurfaceFlinger(  257): id=2635 Removed TurfaceView (-2/8)

I/ActivityManager(  980): Process org.test.lanki:python (pid 2173)(adj 0) has died(104,346)

D/ActivityManager(  980): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: org.test.lanki, Auto Run ON

W/ActivityManager(  980): Force removing ActivityRecord{cdfb7ad u0 org.test.lanki/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity t14123}: app died, no saved state

D/FocusedStackFrame(  980): Set to : 0

I/WindowState(  980): WIN DEATH: Window{319fb08e u0 d0 org.test.lanki/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
```

Comment: Permissions  to access internet are granted ? (If I remember correctly  should be specified from cmd or in buldozer file)

Comment: Post the full adb log.

Comment: Also make sure you have openssl in your requirements. This is necessary to use https.

Comment: `android.permissions = INTERNET` should be in buildozer.spec, is it? Also, not connected directly to question but Kivy has own [requests](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html) and probably also normal requests.get() is acessible.

Comment: What is the type of SSL used in this https link?

Comment: Thanks @JustMe.  Your answer worked; if you post an answer similar to mine I'll delete mine and mark yours approved.

Comment: It's fine with me, since credit goes to inlement in half as well :) and Your answer is concise as it is. Good luck with Kivy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JustMe and @inclement noted in their comments, the answer is to modify `buildozer.spec` so the following two lines are present:

- `android.permissions = INTERNET`
- `openssl` added to the `requirements` line; in my case it became:
  `requirements = fysom, uuid, dropbox, six, kivy, pytz, requests, openssl`